# E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading [Rick Durett's book on probability theory](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) and I was looking for the proof that the expectation of the product of two random variables is the product of the expectation and I think it is given by this theorem.

> **Theorem 2.1.12.**
>
> Suppose $X$ and are $Y$ are independent and have distributions $μ$ and $ν$. If
>   $h:R_2→R$ is a measurable function with $h \ge 0$ or $E|h(X,Y)|< \infty$ then
>   $Eh(X,Y) = \iint h(x,y)μ(dx)ν(dy)$ In particular, if $h(x,y) =f(x)g(y)$
>   where $f,g:R→R$ are measurable functions with $f,g≥0$ or $E|f(X)|$ and
>   $E|g(Y)|< \infty $ then $Ef(X)g(Y) =Ef(X) \cdot Eg(Y)$

So I can take $f(x) = x$ and $g(y)=y$ and then say $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ but we need that $E | X |, E | Y | < \infty$ to apply this theorem but $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ is always true for independent random variables no?

Comment: How can you say  $EXY=EX EY$ when the expectations don't exist? Independence does not guarantee existence of expectations.

Comment: First, handle the finite case using the theorem. Then handle the infinite case, but be careful to properly distinguish infinite from non-existent expectations (remember that for Lebesgue integrals, it only makes sense to assign $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ to an integral if only *either* the positive *or* the negative part diverges!). Show that if one RV has a non-zero expectation and the other an infinite expectation, $XY$ has infinite expectation.

Comment: @roi_saumon : sorry I answered your post thinking that the actual question is "E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)  is always true for independent random variables no?". Now I have some doubts that I interpreted your question correctly... I' m a bit confused, what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @mrcntn Thank you, my question is "from theorem 2.1.12. how do we deduce that E(XY)=E(X)E(Y) for any independent random variables, not only the ones with $E|X|,E|Y|<\infty$"

Comment: If $E|X| = \infty$, $E(X)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

For a RV $Z$ that is the product of two RVs $X$ and $Y$, you have that $E[Z]=E[XY]=E[YX]$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then: $E[XY]=E[X]  E[Y]$.
Assume they are independent, so that the joint PDF is $p_{XY}(x,y) = p_X(x) p_Y(y)$, then 
$$
E[XY]= \int\int \, dx \, dy \, p_Y(y)p_X(x) xy = \int dx \, p_X(x) x \int dy \,  p_Y(y)y = E[X] E[Y] \, .
$$ 
Here the joint PDF in the particular "independent" case $p_X(x) p_Y(y)$ is what your theorem calls $\frac{d\mu}{dx} \,\frac{ d\nu}{dy}$. So the theorem you are considering is valid only for independent RV (because this is implicit in how the measure $d\mu d \nu$ has been written).